# Оптимизация SQL запроса для получения записей

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sql-server

Имеется база данных MySQL. Мне необходимо получать из неё данные и переносить в базу данных MS SQL. Делаю я это с помощью Python. В таблице порядка 30 миллионов записей с большим количеством столбцов. Пробовал получить все записи целиком, но столкнулся с проблемой нехватки ОЗУ и файла подкачки, который вырос до 250GB.

Соответственно было решено разбить получение данных из таблицы на небольшие запросы (в моем текущем случаи на 500.

Я получаю общее кол-во записей в таблице, а после исходя из них в цикле строю SQL запрос:
`SELECT * FROM [таблица] LIMIT 500 OFFSET [последнее значение с которого начинаю новую операцию]`. Всё работает, но возникает проблема со скоростью работы MySQL. Каждый последующий запрос медленнее предыдущего, если первые 500 записей я получаю за долю секунды, то `SELECT * FROM [таблица] LIMIT 500 OFFSET 1000000` я получаю уже за 3-4 минуты, от чего время выполнения растягивается на недели.

Каким путем я могу оптимизировать свой довольно простой и долгий SQL запрос получения записей "от" и "до"?
PS - при всем этом диск, ОЗУ и CPU не загружаются на максимум.

Пробовал многопоточность, чтобы каждый поток получал свои записи:

1. записи от 500 до 1000
2. записи от 1000 до 1500
3. записи от 1500 до 2000

..и т.д на все потоки

При `SELECT * FROM information_schema.processlist;` я вижу результат получения нужных данных, но данный подход особо не ускорил работу.

Comment: Добавьте столбец в таблицу, допустим orderNum, если нет id записи с типом число. orderNum заполните от 1 до последнего, постройте индекс и обращайтесь к таблице как `where orderNum >= 501 and orderNum <=1000`. Если если есть ID целочисленный, то логичнее использовать его.

Comment: Да, есть ID в виде первичного ключа и это действительно ускорило процесс, но время выполнения всё равно оставляет желать лучшего. В скрипте есть счетчик оставшегося времени, который считает общее-кол во записей и высчитывает за сколько была вставлены последние 500 запись, исходя из этого он высчитывает остаток записей и время на вставку всех данных. Приблизительно до 100 тыс. записей всё хорошо, а после каждый новый запрос добавляет несколько секунд. Изначально скрипт должен занять около 20 часов, но подойдя ближе к 500 тыс. записи время выполнения вырастает с 20 часов, до 25.

Comment: Ну вообще-то SQL Server и сам может подключиться к MySQL и забрать с него данные. Чуть сложнее наоборот - чтобы MySQL подключился к SQL Server, но тоже возможно. Посему в упор не вижу необходимости гонять данные на клиента и обратно - клиент просто рулит этим процессом..

Comment: @Akina да, можно сделать миграцию с помощью `SSM Assistent for MySQL` в SQL SERVER и обратно. Он работает куда быстрее моего варианта. В MySQL запросах я вижу, что SSM assistent делает простой запрос "select * from table", возникает вопрос, почему от SSM Assistent получение данных из MySQL и их запись в MS SQL занимает около часа, а в моем примере всё занимает сутки и больше, ведь логика получения/вставки данных идентична.

Comment: Что бы выполнить предложение offset в запросе mysql вынужден сначала перебрать все предыдущие записи с целью их посчитать. Т.е. внутри под капотом при limit 500 offset 1000000 с диска получаются 1000500 записей, из которых первый миллион выбрасывается и возвращается остаток

Comment: по первичному ключу, если запрос вида `select * from table where id > N order by id limit 500` он должен работать на максимум возможностей по скорости. Главное order by не забыть, без него все очень неопределенно выходит.

Comment: @zerxa Может ассистент умный и просто отключает индексы из целевой таблицы перед вставкой? )  Или `bulk insert` каким-то образом использует.

Comment: попробуй обойтись без python, подключись к mysql по связанному серверу из MS SQL и попробуй затянуть таблицу целиком, если нет, то дели на 2,3,4 части, пока не добьёшься желаемой скорости. 30 млн не так много.